How to define a different order for database fields in biblatex?
My school has very specific citation styles. For my thesis I need to cite online sources as follows
I have citations in MWE using this as an example:
John Doe, An Example Source, published by Some publisher, date 2023-05-15, urldate 2023-05-20, url www.example.com.
The MWE attached produces this citation:
Doe, J. An Example Source. Some Publisher. 15. May 2023. URL: www.example.com [cit. 20. 05. 2023].
What I need is for the citation to be like so:
Doe, J. An Example source [online]. Some Publisher. 15. 5. 2023. [cit. 20. 5. 2023]. www.example.com
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top=42mm,
    bottom=42mm,
    inner=35.6mm,
    outer=35.6mm
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=verbose-ibid,
citestyle=verbose-ibid,
sorting=nty,
maxcitenames=1,
giveninits
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Sources.bib}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{abbrv}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[abbrv,1]{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
    \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
    \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\ifboolexpr{
                test {\ifciteibid}
                and
                not test {\iffirstonpage}
            }
            {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}   
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{Sources.bib}
    @online{example,
        author    = {John Doe},
        title     = {An Example Source},
        organization = {Some Publisher},
        date      = {2023-05-15},
        urldate   = {2023-05-20},
        url       = {https://www.example.com}
    }
\end{filecontents}



\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{MUNIblue}{RGB}{0, 0, 220}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\LARGE\color{MUNIblue}} % format
{\thechapter} % label
{1ex} % sep
{} % before-code
[] % after-code

\titleformat
{\section} % command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\Large\color{MUNIblue}} % format
{\thesection} % label
{1ex} % sep
{} % before-code
[] % after-code

\titleformat
{\subsection} % command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\large\color{MUNIblue}} % format
{\thesubsection} % label
{1ex} % sep
{} % before-code
[] % after-code

%\usepackage{sectsty}
%   \chapterfont{\color{MUNIblue}}
%   \sectionfont{\color{MUNIblue}}
%   \subsectionfont{\color{MUNIblue}}
%   \subsubsectionfont{\color{MUNIblue}}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url} 
\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks
    \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
    \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
    \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
    \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
    \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
    \do\Y\do\Z\do\*\do\-\do\~\do\'\do\"\do\-}%

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcomma\space s.\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\addperiod\space}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\nopunct}{}{}
\makeatletter\xpatchcmd\@dottedtocline{\normalcolor}{}{}{\fail}\makeatother

\xpatchbibdriver{online}{\printfield{note}\newunit\newblock}{\printfield{note}\newunit\newblock
    \printfield{publisher+date}%
}



\DeclareTextFontCommand{\ar}{\sffamily}






\setlength{\parskip}{0,5 em}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\linespread{1}

\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000


\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    
    {\color{MUNIblue}\tableofcontents}

    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \chapter*{Závěr}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Závěr}
    \par \blindtext \footcite{example}
    
    
    
    \pagebreak
    
    \begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    
    {\bfseries\LARGE\color{MUNIblue}\flushleft{Seznam použitých zdrojů}}
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Seznam použitých zdrojů}
    \printbibliography[
    title={Monografie},
    type=book]
    \printbibliography[
    title={Články},
    type=article]
    \printbibliography[
    title={Elektronické zdroje},
    type=online]
    \endgroup
\end{document}


Maybe look into https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-iso690? Some of the features you describe seem pretty ISO-690-y.
